# create --help for a custom script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I create a --help switch for my custom bash script?
I googled it but I could not find a useful thing.
I am looking for a usual way of it.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? `--help` is just an argument, you handle it like any other potential argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the arguments and decide what to do each one. For example:

```
function help_text() {
        echo <<EOT
This is your help text.
Blabla.
EOT
}

while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
        case "$1" in
                --help)
                        help_text
                        exit
                        ;;

                --some-other-flag)
                        echo "Do something else"
                        ;;

                *)      echo "Not a flag: $1"
                        ;;
        esac

        shift # Get next argument
done
```

Comment: Is function name `help` & call `help_test` typo?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some reference material for how to do this:

http://linuxcommand.org/wss0130.php

The section "Command line options" shows you how to parse the options, and, depending on what you pass (e.g. -h, --help, etc.) you can call a function to display help.

Answer (score 1):

```
(( $# == 1 )) && [[ "$1" == "--help" ]] && echo "this is the help"
```

Comment: I knew that but I was looking for a special command .is this the way that used by other scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

Getopt is the keyword you are looking for.